# Azure storage queue picking up all messages concurrently

Tags: azure, storage

I am using the azure storage queue in my application and it looks like my queue is not behaving like a proper queue (FIFO). It picks up all messages concurrently and start processing them.

What should I be doing so that the queue picks up messages in a FIFO manner (one by one)?

Comment: Please share your code. Most likely you're getting more than one message at a time in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Azure Storage Queue doesn't provide **Ordering guarantee**, you could find the [description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted#additional-information).

> Messages in Storage queues are typically first-in-first-out, but
>   sometimes they can be out of order; for example, when a message's
>   visibility timeout duration expires

However you could use Service Bus to get the FIFO guarantee. And this is the [comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted#foundational-capabilities) between Storage Queue and Service Bus. It says the FIFO is implemented through the use 
of messaging sessions.

Further information about Service Bus, you could refer to this doc [Azure Service Bus Messaging Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/).